# Where is the win32 class?

Tags: c#

In many locations, I see win32.Point or win32.Size used, for example [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.updatelayeredwindow) or [here](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/Win32.POINT/-/php-win32.point-class-examples.html).

Where do I find this win32 class? 
Or is it just something imaginary / a placeholder, and every reader has to create his own?

Comment: Strangely enough, a Google search for "win32 point" returns https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-point - I think you need to do some research and understand what P/Invoke is and what it does.

Comment: You don't answer the question if it's an imaginary class. I mean people use it all over the place like it exists, like System.Drawing or so, but I didn't find it. So my question is legit and not something worth downvoting.

Comment: 'win32 point' is a structure, not a class.  Its a real thing documented as such.  But not everything works like NET does with all these references prebuilt and predefined.  So, it is not imaginary but you do have to type it in and apply certain conversions such as the `long` listed there would be a NET `int32`

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp You typed "win32 point", but in the links I gave, they typed "win32.point". So "win" is a class, and "point" is a member of this class. So it is indeed a class, right?

Comment: So?  If you look at your own link you will see code with a class named `win32`  which contains a `public struct Point`.  They typed it in and followed the specs via the MS Docs link *with* the long -> int32 change I mentioned.  Also, if you check you will find the **[NET definition of that Point structure](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/POINT.html?diff=y)** as well.  the dot notation in `win32.Point` is an artifact of that example.

Comment: It is worth mentioning the preferred or recommended way to organize these is to create a NativeMethods class and store your PInvoke code and methods there.  Anything else - like a win32 class - and the MS code analyzers will complain

Comment: Thanks for telling me that it's shown on the same page, I simply didn't spot it. My question was simply if it was perfect a class defined by Microsoft or so since I saw it used in so many places. And that was my question: "Where is the win32 class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody wrote in a comment that the win32 class is stated exactely in one of the links that I posted:

https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.updatelayeredwindow

One has to scroll down quite a bit to see it.